# Iron Router and Meteor 1.0.2.1

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

When I run on my computer, everything inorder, and when the load on meteor.chom then receive  message "iron:router Organize your Meteor application."

That's my file with configs

```
Router.route( '/', function(){
if (this.ready()) {
    this.render('content', {});
 } else {
    this.render('Loading');
}}
```

)

'Content' - template with my data. 
There are link on one of template : `<a href="{{pathFor 'csv'}}">Convert to CSV and download</a>`.
That's configurations for it

```
Router.route('/csv', {
  where: 'server',
  action: function () {
    var filename = 'venues' + '.csv';
    var csv = new CSV1();

    var fileData =  csv.fromJsonToCsv(Venues.find().fetch());

    var headers = {
      'Content-type': 'text/csv',
      'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
    };
    this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
    return this.response.end(fileData);
  }
});
```

Why server (meteor.com) send message (error) ?
And second questions: Link "Convert to CSV and download" is work only after first click. How this fix? Needed that it working after on all clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing "iron:router Organize your Meteor application." means either that you don't have routing code on your site or that there's an error in the router code.  Have you looked at the server console output to see what's going on?  Your first router code sample works perfectly in a minimal test app I've created here.